# Unable to set up lan in macbook pro ( with retina display)

Tags: network, internet, ethernet

In macbook pro there is no lan port, for that I bought lan to usb connector.

But I am unable to setup net-connection.

In System preference > networks there is no ethernet option.

[image]

I tried this link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4835488?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: As long it is not plugged in there will be none.

Comment: Ethernet connection not appears after plugging in.

Comment: Than there is no juice on the cable!

Comment: @TLE Please edit the title and content to clarify that you are using a MacBook Pro with Retina Display (or MacBook Air) and a Thunderbolt Ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 2):

There's a add button at the bottom right portion of that screenshot. Click it.

It will present you with options to add a new interface, and if wired Ethernet is available on your Mac, it will appear there.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't show any Ethernet option .

Comment: @TLE Goto System Profiler and select Ethernet from the sidebar to see if any Ethernet device is available. Or if using USB/Thunderbolt adapter, try going to their respected section and see if the device is shown.

Comment: http://www.domosupport.com/download.php  I am using U1 model of nhance product. I tried to download drivers of that product but didn't find dmg file.

Comment: This link has detailed information to installing kext manually. http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/12/how-to-manually-install-kernel-extensions-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Extract `Archive.pax.gz` file and you will get a kext file. You could install that kext file copying that to `/System/Library/Extensions` and then fixing disk permission with Disk Utility which will install that driver. This is NOT recommended, since that might crash your system. I will suggest buying a dongle that works out of the box, like ones from Apple.

Comment: I tried to move that file, but it gives error "not properly installed".

Comment: Have you follow osxdaily's steps?